# Scrape to download online file python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data from a downloadable file in this page:

```
https://www.abcbourse.com/download/libelles
```

I need to validate the `checkbox` on SBF120 and click on `Télécharger`

here is my code but I don't know which parameters should I add:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.abcbourse.com/download/libelles"
params = {}

r = requests.get(url, params=params)
data = r.json()
```

Comment: If you open developer tools in your browser (in firefox using Ctrl+Shift+I) in the network tab, when you click that button, the website sends a POST request to get the result, you must emulate that request to get response

Answer (score 0):

Alternativ to POST request, that requires an token is using selenium.

**Very basic example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.abcbourse.com/download/libelles'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
# get rid of the cookie popup
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.sd-cmp-1rLJX').click()
# click the checkbox
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="xsbf120p"]').click()
# click submit button
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn_abc.ml20').click()

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use selenium, here's an easy guide:
 Quickly install selenium: `pip3 install selenium`
 Install the [Mozilla Firefox webdriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) (*choose the one based on your
OS*)

Once you're done with the above steps, the following code should work smoothly:
(This will download the ".csv" file in your downloads folder, ✅ tested on Mac)

```
import os, time
from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == "__main__":

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 1) 
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv')

    browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get("https://www.abcbourse.com/download/libelles")    
    time.sleep(8)

    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.sd-cmp-1rLJX').click()
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="xsbf120p"]').click()
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn_abc.ml20').click()
    browser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to download the required file from that site using requests module:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.abcbourse.com/download/libelles'

payload = {
    'cbox': 'xsbf120p',
    'cbPlace': 'false'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    payload['__RequestVerificationToken'] = soup.select_one("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']")['value']
    with open("libelles.csv","wb") as f:
        f.write(s.post(link,data=payload).content)
```

Comment: Create a folder in your desktop. Put the script within the folder and run it so that you can get the downloaded csv file within the same folder.